# Properly Resolving Import Errors with Directories

Tags: python

My question here is more about the appropriate way to resolve import errors in a way that is considered "Pythonically correct," if there is such a term. I thought I had solution to my problem (posted below and updated), but even that turns out not work.

**Context**

I have looked at various responses to this (like [How to resolve import errors in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456068/how-to-resolve-import-errors-in-python)) and I think I've done those things, but I still have the question that I'm posting here.

**Example**

I have the following structure:

```
pacumen
  rules
    __init__.py
    pacman_rules.py
  pacman.py
  game.py
```

In `pacman_rules.py` I have a class:

```
class PacmanRules:
    ....
```

In my `pacman.py` file, I have the following import statement:

```
from rules.pacman_rules import PacmanRules
```

Mind you, this was auto-generated by PyCharm. So PyCharm shows me that it resolves just fine.

However, when I run `pacman.py` from the command line, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name PacmanRules
```

I have no idea why that's happening in this case, given the lines of code.

In `pacman.py` I also have this statement:

```
from game import GameStateData
```

That one is working just fine. Notice that the class `GameStateData` comes from my `game.py` file. So I'm guessing my issue is that I'm trying to import from a file in a different directory rather than from a file in the same directory.

**Possible Solution (Update: Does Not Work)**

So then I tried this import instead:

```
from rules import pacman_rules
```

That seems to work, but it requires me to change lines like this:

```
PacmanRules.getLegalActions(self)
```

to lines like this:

```
pacman_rules.PacmanRules.getLegalActions(self)
```

That just feels messy to me and seems to defeat the purpose of importing a class name so I can use it without having to preface it.

But, as it turns out, this doesn't work either. This just gets a different error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name pacman_rules
```

So that's my question here. Most questions seem to revolve around *how* to fix the issue; as it turns out I don't even have a "fix."

What I'm curious about is why the initial approach doesn't work (especially since PyCharm generates it) and if my proposed solution is the appropriate way to handle this.

Comment: is there anything in your rules/__init__.py file?  (I'm grasping at straws.)

Comment: @ChrisCurvey Good point; I should have mentioned that. No, `__init__.py` is empty. But you pointed me to the solution, I think. In that file I could instead put this: `from pacman_rules import PacmanRules`. Then in `pacman.py` I can just have `from rules import PacmanRules`. That _seems_ to do the trick. I'm not sure if using the init file that way is preferred.

Comment: Hmm. Take that back, while it does show correct in PyCharm, running from the command line still says it cannot import PacmanRules.